# Is there a binary literal in Interbase?

Tags: literals, interbase

I have downloaded a trial version of Interbase 2017, and am using Windows 64 bit builds, and ODBC drivers on Windows 10 Pro Version 1703.

I created a database like this

```
CREATE TABLE "REBBINARY" (ID integer, "SQLVALUE" CHAR(3) NOT NULL)
```

and attempt to insert some binary data like this

```
INSERT INTO "REBBINARY" ("SQLVALUE") VALUES (x'000000')
```

which works fine in Firebird.

But I get this error

```
** Error: [ODBC InterBase Driver][InterBase]Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 1, char 47
'000000'
```

So, what's the correct literal for binary data in statements?

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Interbase's current developer

> InterBase does not offer a literal binary. The only way that you can add a binary value to a char field would be to use a parameterised query. For example, FireDAC's TFDParam offers the AsByteStr property: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FireDAC.Stan.Param.TFDParam.AsByteStr